# Styling searchView (white color)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styling, searchview

is there a way to hide the icon shown in this screenshot http://s2.postimg.org/8nip77c7d/aaaa.png 
........(it looks like my post is mostly code, so i add this )
here is my code :

```
    sv = new SearchView(context);
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mi.setActionView(sv); 

    int searchIconId = sv.getContext().getResources().
            getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) sv.findViewById(searchIconId);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_action_search);

    try {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
          sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        Field searchField = null;

        searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mCloseButton");

        searchField.setAccessible(true);
        ImageView closeBtn = null;
        closeBtn = (ImageView) searchField.get(sv);


        closeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_content_clear); 
        int searchTextViewId = sv.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView searchTextView = (TextView)  sv.findViewById(searchTextViewId);
        searchTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
        Log.e("sv",e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        Log.e("sv",e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by writing hint , by adding this code at the end of the previous one

```
        searchTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        searchTextView.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#aaffffff"));
        searchTextView.setHint(getString(R.string.recherche));
```

screenshot here http://s16.postimg.org/yt1wogfx1/Screenshot_2015_04_13_22_11_35.png

Comment: what is your app theme ?